# rmagick or other library for producing 3D pie chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, imagemagick, rmagick, pie-chart

I am interested in making a 3D pie chart dynamically on my page depending on values pulled from my database. The chart would only be updated every few days, so I don't mind a process intensive task as I could cache the image. 2D charts and pie graph libraries seem to be everywhere, but are there any libraries (server side image magic, or client side javascript) that generate decent looking 3D pie charts?

Extra points if it integrates easily into Ruby-On-Rails.

[An example of the type of chart I am looking for can be found on the bottom of this page](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/1_billionth_spam_message_stats.php).

Comment: Looks like google Charts is another option http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ . If anyone else has another good, free (or cheapish) solution to post, i'll vote you up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this flash based [plugin](http://ezgraphixdemo.heroku.com/) that supports Pie 3D, it's not rmagick, but it's easy to use and setup with Rails.

Comment: that looks great, I would prefer a static image for compatibility, reasons but if you're the only show in town I certainly wouldn't mind using flash. Good work on the site!

Comment: Hey, thanks, You should also take a look on the Gruff ( http://nubyonrails.com/pages/gruff ) gem, it makes image based graphics, I hope it helps you.